# Why can’t I run a specific .x86 file on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to play [Baldi’s Basics](https://basically-games.itch.io/baldis-basics). OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Lenovo B590 laptop.

But when I try to, I get a error saying no program is chosen as the program to open it.

I try to use the terminal and this is what happens:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/BALDI_1.4.3_Linux$ ./BALDI.x86
bash:
./BALDI.x86: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

This is kind of interesting. When I don’t do:

```
chmod +x BALDI.x86
```

It just says “Permission denied”:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/BALDI_1.4.3_Linux$ ./BALDI.x86
bash:
./BALDI.x86: Permission denied
```

But when I do the `chmod +x` command:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/BALDI_1.4.3_Linux$ ./BALDI.x86
bash:
./BALDI.x86: No such file or directory
```

It seems like bash apparently does not find the file anymore. Pretty weird huh?

Here is the output of `ls`, `file`, and `ldd`.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/BALDI_1.4.3_Linux$ file BALDI.x86
BALDI.x86: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=962
3df3ee5a4bcdoddob4aa7f340a41324be7b90, stripped
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/BALDI 1.4.3 Linux$ ldd BALDI.x86
not a dynamic executable
```

Here is the output of `ls -l`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/BALDI_1.4.3 Linux$ ls -l
total 53628
drwxrwxr-x 6 ubuntu ubuntu 900 Feb 25 16:44 BALDI Data
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 27391884 Feb 25 2019 BALDI.x86
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 27513640 Feb 25 2019 BALDI.x86_64
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3894 Jun 17 2019 README.txt
```

Comment: It seems you haven't the file `BALDI.x86` ! What is the content of the directory?

Comment: "How do I fix this?" - Navigate to the correct location of the executable.  The error you are getting isn't one that indicates the application failed to execute, rather that, the executable does not even exist.

Comment: This message can also show up if the loader cannot be found, for example if the 32-bit loader is not installed on the 64-bit system. The user should try `file BALDI.x86` and `ldd BALDI.x86` for more information.

Comment: alright I am in the directory where the baldi basics is.

Comment: when i try to run it i get the bash error

Comment: Give us a `ls -l` of the directory.

Comment: ok i gave ls output

Comment: x86 is 32bit architecture. I doubt your modern machine is running a 32bit OS. So try running `BALDI.x86_64`; and be sure to `chmod a+x BALDI.x86_64` as well to allow it to run.

Comment: thanks, it worked.

Comment: @SusuLaku Please do not [edit the question to say “Issue Solved”](https://superuser.com/posts/1706928/revisions) like you just did. If a comment worked to solve an issue, encourage the commenter to post a full answer. Then be sure to check that answer off as the answer that solved your problem. This site is not a forum and comments are just lightweight comments presenting ideas that _might_ work. Full answers are what solve issues and what this site encourages be done. I will post a full answer shortly.

Comment: @SusuLaku Full answer [posted here](https://superuser.com/a/1706972/167207).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You seem to be trying to run the 32bit version of the game and not the 64bit version.

x86 is 32bit architecture. I doubt your modern Lenovo B590 laptop which is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is running a 32bit version of the Ubuntu OS.

So try running the `BALDI.x86_64` binary that is right there in that directory as well.

That should work and be sure to `chmod a+x BALDI.x86_64` as well to allow the binary to have executable rights so it can run to begin with.

Comment: When are multilib support removed from Ubuntu? `dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then adding a few libraries should enable 32-bit application support. 64-bit systems can certainly run 32-bit binaries.

Comment: @doneal24 You have a point. But did you see this binary and what it is? It’s just a silly hacker game. It is not my job to dig deeper as to how rushed code may or may not work. The original poster indicated my solution works so that’s all that really matters here.